# Run SQL post DB creation but pre migrations with pytest

Tags: django, postgresql, pytest, pytest-django

I have a django project that some of its models use a special index.
For this reason i create a extension in my db pre-migrations.
When i run the tests, pytest creates a test db and runs the migrations but no extension is created. I cannot create the extension inside the migrations. Is there any way to insert a "RunSQL" command on the test db after db creation but before the migrations run?
Tech stuff:

- Django 1.9.5
- pytest
- postgres 9.5

Comment: If you want to insert "RunSQL" before testing you can do that by making a [fixtures](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html), if this is what you want

Comment: The exact point i want to run the SQL is after the pytest creates the DB but before it runs the migrations. The migrations will fall if the extension is not created in the DB.

Comment: @MrT. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: The solution was to create the extension in the template DB of postgres so the DB will be create whith the extension directly